# Isomorphic $R$-module which are not isomorphic $R$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

I'm reading ''COHOMOLOGY OPERATIONS AND APPLICATIONS HOMOTOPY THEORY'' by R. E. Mosher and M.C. Tangora. At the beginning of the six chapter the following is explained:

Assume $R$ is afield and let $A = (A_i)_i$ be a Hopf algebr over $R$ of finite type (that is each $A_i$ is finite-dimensional over $R$). We define the dual Hopf algebra to $A,$ $A^*$ by setting $$A^* = (A_i^*)_i,\quad A_i^* = \mbox{Hom}_R(A_i, R)$$ that is the dual to $A_i$ as a vector space over $R.$ So $A^*$ is a Hopf algebra over $R$ of finite type.

My question is

Show that $A$ and $A^*$ are isomorphic as $R$-module but certainly not as $R$-algebra in general?

I know that $A$ and $A^*$ are isomorphic as $R$-module but I don't understand why $A$ and $A^*$ not as $R$-algebra in general.

I hope that someone, can help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with a few examples. Like a group algebra?

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft. I want to ask $A$ is a Hopf algebra over R of finite type.then $A^*$ is a Hopf algebra over R of finite type or $A^*$ is a Hopf algebra?

Comment: That is a completely different question than the one you asked here. And yes, the dual is also a Hopf algebra of finite type.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft.  Why the dual of a group algebra is not isomorphic  group algebra?

Comment: Because a group algebra is always cocommutative but not always commutative.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft. The dual of a group algebra is always commutative?

Comment: Yes, by virtue of the group algebra itself being cocommutative.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition:** Let $(H, \mu, \eta, \Delta, \varepsilon,S)$ a finite dimensional 
$k$-Hopf algebra. Then the dual v.s. $Η^{\ast}$,
equipped with the $k$-algebra structure the dual of the $k$-coalgebra $(H, \Delta,
\varepsilon)$ and $k$-coalgebra structure the dual of the $k$-algebra $(H, \mu,
\eta)$ form a $k$-Hopf algebra: 
$$
(H^{\ast} \; , \;
\Delta^{\ast}\!\!\!\circ\!\!\lambda \; , \;
 \varepsilon^{\ast}\!\!\!\circ\!\!\psi \; , \;
\lambda^{-1}\!\!\circ\!\mu^{\ast} \; , \;
\psi^{-1}\!\!\circ\!\eta^{\ast},S^*)
$$
which will be called the **dual Hopf algebra of $Η$**.
(In the above, we denote with $\psi$, the natural v.s. isomorphism 
$k\cong k^*$ defined by $\psi(\kappa)=f$ with $f(1)=\kappa$ and $\psi^{-1}(f)=f(1)$ and with $\lambda:A^*\otimes A^*\rightarrow(A\otimes A)^*$ the linear v.s. injection, defined by $\lambda(f\otimes g)(u\otimes v)=f(u)g(v)\in k$. In case $A$ is of finite $k$-dimension then $\lambda$ is a vector space isomorphism).

Thus, the answer to your question is that **the algebraic structure of the dual  Hopf algebra is determined by the coalgebraic structure of the initial Hopf algebra**. So, it does not have to be necessarily isomorphic to the initial algebra.

**Example:**
As an example of the above, you can see the construction of the dual group Hopf algebra $(kG)^*$ of the group Hopf algebra $kG$ of a finite group $G$:
Let $G$ a finite group and $k$ the field. For simplicity consider $k$ algebraically closed and of characteristic zero. 
Let the dual space $(kG)^{*}$:
$$
k^{G}=Map(G,k) \cong Hom(kG,k)=(kG)^{*}
$$
$k^{G}$ is the v.s. of set maps from $G$ to $k$. Since $dim_{k}(kG)^{*}=|G|< \infty$ we can pick as a $k$-basis of the dual space the dual of the $k\mathbb{G}$ basis
$\{ g /g \in G \}$, i.e.: $\{ p_{g} /g \in G \}$ where
$p_{g}(h) = \delta_{g,h}$ for all $g \in G$ and for all $h \in
G$.
Applying the above proposition, we get the following maps for the dual $k$-Hopf algebra $(kG)^{*}$ of the group Hopf algebra $kG$:

- comultiplication:
  $$
  \Delta(p_{g})=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
    g_{1},g_{2} \in G \\
    g_{1}g_{2}=g \\
  \end{array}}p_{g_{1}} \otimes p_{g_{2}}=\sum_{x \in G}p_{x}
  \otimes p_{x^{-1}g}
  $$
- counity:
  $$
  \varepsilon(p_{g}) = p_{g}(1_{G}) = \delta_{g,1_{G}}
  $$
- multiplication:
  $$
  \big( p_{g_{1}} \star p_{g_{2}}
  \big)(h)=p_{g_{1}}(h)p_{g_{2}}(h)=\delta_{g_{1},h}
  \delta_{g_{2},h}= \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    0, \;\;\;\;\;\; g_{1} \neq g_{2} \\
    \delta_{g,h}, \;\; g_{1} = g_{2} = g \\
  \end{array} \right.
  $$
  thus: $p_{g}^{2}=p_{g}$ and $p_{g} \star p_{h}=0$ if $g \neq
  h$. In other words,  the basis $\{ p_{g} /g \in G \}$ of $(kG)^{*}$
  consists of orthogonal idempotents, implying that:
- the unity map is determined by 
  $$
  \sum_{g \in G}p_{g}=1_{(kG)^{*}}
  $$
  The above imply the $k$-algebra isomorphism
  $$
  (kG)^{*} \cong k \times k \times \cdots \times k \equiv k^{(n)}
  $$
  given explicitly by: $p_{g}
  \leftrightarrow (0,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0) $ ($1$ lies at the $g$-th entry and  $n=|G|$).
  We thus conclude that $(kG)^{*}$ is commutative and semisimple (remember that $kG$ is cocommutative and cosemisimple but in general not commutative since the group $G$ was not assumed to be abelian; this an example of duality). **Thus $kG$ and $(kG)^*$ are certainly not isomorphic as algebras** (in general).
- Finally, the antipode of the dual is given by: $S^{*}(p_{g}) = p_{g^{-1}}$

Comment: @ KonKan. Why $(kG)^*$ is semisimple?

Comment: Because it is a direct product of copies of $k$ (as it has been shown above).

Comment: @ KonKan Thank you very much!

Comment: If something is missing let me know.

Comment: @ KonKan Let $M$ be a $R$-module. Show that exists a unital $R$-algebra structure over R-module $M$? Can you help me?Thanks!

Comment: @lony: this is a completely different question. You should post it as a separate question. The comments area is not suitable for this.

Comment: @ KonKan My question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059866/r-algebra-structure-over-r-module?noredirect=1#comment4228376_2059866